# Angular 7 Phalcon multi module structure

Tags: angular, angular7, phalcon

I have read a lot about multi modular structure for angular projects however they are assuming frontend will be completely separated from API. Kinda don't like that approach.

For example multi modular application will have api controllers for:

- Crud
- Media
- Cms
- Auth
- Etc.

And there is no logical separation between frontend for Auth and backend for it. Frontend will just not work without backend.

So I was thinking how to handle this. My Phalcon structure (with customized fully autonomical modules) looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc1Q1.png

[image]

And big question comes. **Should I put angular files inside these modules?**

Basically we have big system that we also use for clients so we need to be able to quickly detach some of the modules without breaking too much.

That would be harder if frontend would stay separate.

Also, we want to run frontend thru the same server as backend, quite possibly redirecting any request to angular while having all of these modules behind `/api`

Comment: Personally I would keep client-side code separate from backend.  How would it be harder?  If there's an issue on the backend why muck up the debug process by having to search through all this intertwined frontend code?

Comment: Pretty simple, if you have code scattered all over the files its just harder to navigate. I like to have *logic* separation, not *technology* separation.

Comment: This is an opinionated post, therefore not great for SO, but if that's what works for you then go for it.  Personally, building frontend code that's intermixed with backend can cause issues as opposed to having it clumped into its own "domain" in your tree.  Do what works for you. There's no right answer here.

Comment: There is one thing that keeps me from doing it straight away: import paths, is there a way to tell angular/webpack he should search some other directories for module?